# Solution of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the ODE $$y''+p(x)y'+2y = 0$$ has solutions $y$ and $y^2$, find $y$ and $p(x)$.

**My approach:** 
I took $Y(x) = y + y^2$ to be the solution of the above ODE.By substituting the solution I got $(Y')^2 = 0$, which gives $Y(x) = \text{constant}$. I am not able to think how to find $y$ and $p(x)$.

Comment: You might want to review [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931038/second-order-equation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $y^{2}$ is a solution, one has
\begin{align*}
& (y^{2})^{\prime\prime} + p(x)(y^{2})^{\prime} + 2y^{2} = 0 \Longrightarrow (2yy^{\prime})^{\prime} + 2p(x)yy^{\prime} + 2y^{2} =0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& 2(y^{\prime})^{2} + 2yy^{\prime\prime} + 2p(x)yy^{\prime} + 2y^{2} = 0 \Longrightarrow \frac{(y^{\prime})^{2}}{y} + y^{\prime\prime} + p(x)y^{\prime} + y = 0 \Longrightarrow\\\\
& \frac{(y^{\prime})^{2}}{y} - y = 0 \Longrightarrow (y^{\prime})^{2} = y^{2} \Longrightarrow |y^{\prime}| = |y| \Longrightarrow y^{\prime} = \pm y \Longrightarrow y = \exp(\pm x)
\end{align*}

where it has been used that $y^{\prime\prime} + p(x)y^{\prime} + 2y = 0$. Once you have the expression for $y$, you can plug it in the original equation and find out the expression for $p(x)$. Based on it, can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah, I can proceed from here. I made a mistake while solving it. I got it. Thanks.